# How to check transporting some data to the port?

Tags: python, django, tcpdump

I use Django 1.6 and Python 2.7

It is my tcpdump command.

```
sudo /usr/sbin/tcpdump -n -X port 3331
```

And I kick the command from python because I'd like to use it in Django.

```
import subprocess as sub

def tcpdump(request, port):    
    result = 'nothing'

    count = 0
    proc = sub.Popen(['sudo', 'tcpdump', '-n', '-X', 'port', str(port)], stdout=sub.PIPE)    

    try:
        for row in proc.stdout:
            print row.rstrip()   # process here
            result = str(row.rstrip())
            count += 1
            if count > 10:
                break
    except:
        print 'tcpdump error'
        proc.terminate()

    return HttpResponse(result)
```

I wrote in the `views.py`.

urls.py

`url(r'^tcpdump(?P<port>\d+)/$', tcpdump),`

I will just access to http://some.url/tcpdump3331

This `row.rstrip()` get multiple lines string, and I'd like to do timeout.

Could you tell me better practice?

Comment: Is the `tcpdump` command run from the Django app ? Or is it from a different process ? Why can't you simply use `tcpdump` from the shell/bash script/cron job/at process ? What should trigger the port capture ? How long should run the capture ? As a final note: _"I'd like to use it in Django"_  **having your web server running with enough privileges to either execute `sudo` or to perform a port dump seems a major security threat to me**. But YMMV.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Thank you for replying.
I'd like to capture some data from the port I selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to run tcpdump from your app. The point is that it sniffs the network traffic, and logs network packets regardless of the applications generating the traffic. You do not even have to run it on the same computer, where your server is running, just run in on the same subnet.

You can also use GUI tools like wireshark which is easier to configure.

Comment: Thank you for replying.
I am sending sound data from client via port, and I'd like to check the data by Django.